# Hybrid Ellpack-Itpack (ELL) + COO Sparse Matrix Representation decomposition threshold

Tags: algorithms, linear-solver, sparse-matrix, data-structures

Hybrid **ELL-COO** sparse matrix representation can be done as in the picture, I was looking intensively, however I couldn't find out what is the ***threshold*** of decomposing the original matrix into **ELL** part and **COO** part, how to divide the original matrix **A** ?

[image: hybrid ell-coo sparse matrix representation]